# Can I Use GitHub for Managing Directories and Files in my External Hard Disk?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am on Windows 7

I Want to use GitHub or some similar software to Manage my External Hard Disk

There are movies and serials in my External Hard Disk

Can I make a record of who added new movies or deleted some movies

Can I do it with GitHub or suggest some other software ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea: git will store in its history also deleted stuff (in order to be able to restore a previous revision), so it's going to take much more space than necessary.

Comment: I cannot recommend anything but I can definitely tell you that you don't want to manage large binary files with git much less GitHub. There is a StackExchange site for software recommendations. You could ask there.

Comment: @SimonePalazzo Suppose I dont want to push or pull or restore any deleted files, I just only want track of whats added, deleted...then what would you suggest, can I use it ?

Comment: It's not a matter of whether you are going to restore anything; git WILL keep copies of all deleted (or modified, but that's not likely to happen with movies) files. I don't think you can tell git not to do that (but you can check, maybe it's possible, I only use git at a relatively basic level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no current utility program that can run on your External Hard Disk and log all the past modification on it.

This program should be made by your constructor and he is probably not giving you such service.

All you can do to keep traking thses information is to keep a script with the history of modifications in it. For exemple :

```
Nov 27, 2014 - Fumbo - Adding New Serie : The Flash
Nov 27, 2014 - Fumbo - Removing Film : Frozen.mkv
```

To do so you can make a python script that will take some parameters and create the log line.

```
python logging.py add-serie "The Flash"
python logging.py rm-film "Frozen.mkv"
```

That script utility could be limitless.

Or you can also keep track of it by hand in the file, I think the usage of git here is too much.

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Yes That Helped Me
Trying to Write Own Program Like you Told, that would be the best solution, i think